# Cakephp3 - Cant find $theme property that throws an error

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I have upgraded from Cakephp3 v3 to v3.3 (using Composer) and I get the following error:

```
Deprecated (16384): Property $theme is deprecated.
Use $this->viewBuilder()->theme() instead in beforeRender().
[CORE/src/View/ViewVarsTrait.php, line 103]
```

But I can't find in my files where **$theme** is used. I have searched all my files for the keyword **$theme** and **beforeRender**, no relevant results.

This error is shown in all my pages, so it must be some file that is included in each one.

I have already searched on google for this issue, no relevant results either.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Full error stack:

```html
$viewClass = null
$builder = object(Cake\View\ViewBuilder) {
 [protected] _templatePath => 'Users'
 [protected] _template => 'login'
 [protected] _plugin => null
 [protected] _theme => 'Orange'
 [protected] _layout => null
 [protected] _autoLayout => null
 [protected] _layoutPath => null
 [protected] _name => null
 [protected] _className => null
 [protected] _options => []
 [protected] _helpers => []
}
$validViewOptions = [
 (int) 0 => 'passedArgs'
]
$viewOptions = [
 'passedArgs' => []
]
$option = 'passedArgs'
$this = object(App\Controller\UsersController) {
 theme => 'Orange'
 name => 'Users'
 helpers => []
 request => object(Cake\Network\Request) {}
 response => object(Cake\Network\Response) {}
 paginate => []
 autoRender => false
 components => []
 View => null
 plugin => null
 passedArgs => []
 modelClass => 'Users'
 viewClass => null
 viewVars => []
 Flash => object(Cake\Controller\Component\FlashComponent) {}
 Auth => object(Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent) {}
 [protected] _responseClass => 'Cake\Network\Response'
 [protected] _components => object(Cake\Controller\ComponentRegistry) {}
 [protected] _validViewOptions => [
  (int) 0 => 'passedArgs'
 ]
 [protected] _eventManager => object(Cake\Event\EventManager) {}
 [protected] _eventClass => '\Cake\Event\Event'
 [protected] _tableLocator => object(Cake\ORM\Locator\TableLocator) {}
 [protected] _modelFactories => [
  'Table' => [
   [maximum depth reached]
  ]
 ]
 [protected] _modelType => 'Table'
 [protected] _viewBuilder => object(Cake\View\ViewBuilder) {}
}
$deprecatedOptions = [
 'layout' => 'layout',
 'view' => 'template',
 'theme' => 'theme',
 'autoLayout' => 'autoLayout',
 'viewPath' => 'templatePath',
 'layoutPath' => 'layoutPath'
]
$new = 'theme'
$old = 'theme'

Cake\Controller\Controller::createView() - CORE/src/View/ViewVarsTrait.php, line 103
Cake\Controller\Controller::render() - CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 616
Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php, line 131
Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php, line 99
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 65
[main] - ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 21
```

Comment: is that the full error message? Are you using any plugin? Maybe the problem in in a plugin component

Comment: @arilia I use no plugins, And yes, that is the full error message.

Comment: you don't have to search for the keyword `$theme` as it use to be an attribute of the controller object. Search for `theme` or for `->theme`. I would look into my AppController or my components, idf any

Comment: also usually if you click on the error message header (deprecated...) you will see the whole error stack and the exact line that fired that error

Comment: @arilia thank you for your help with this. I have posted the full error stack. Searching for __->theme__ didn't help.

Comment: where does that 'Orange' theme come from? I could replicate your exact error setting `public $theme = 'Orange';` in UsersController or in AppController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in AppController a custom theme (Orange in my case) needs to be declared as:

```
public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->theme('Orange');
}
```

and not like

```
public $theme = 'Orange';
```

Many thanks to @arilia for helping me with this.